# How to change existing tag information in Magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to update the popularity count of Magento's Tag module by interacting with this core function in `Mage_Tag_Model_API`

```
    public function update($tagId, $data, $store)
{
    $data = $this->_prepareDataForUpdate($data);
    $storeId = $this->_getStoreId($store);
    /** @var $tag Mage_Tag_Model_Tag */
    $tag = Mage::getModel('tag/tag')->setStoreId($storeId)->setAddBasePopularity()->load($tagId);
    if (!$tag->getId()) {
        $this->_fault('tag_not_exists');
    }

    // store should be set for 'base_popularity' to be saved in Mage_Tag_Model_Resource_Tag::_afterSave()
    $tag->setStore($storeId);
    if (isset($data['base_popularity'])) {
        $tag->setBasePopularity($data['base_popularity']);
    }
    if (isset($data['name'])) {
        $tag->setName(trim($data['name']));
    }
    if (isset($data['status'])) {
        // validate tag status
        if (!in_array($data['status'], array(
            $tag->getApprovedStatus(), $tag->getPendingStatus(), $tag->getDisabledStatus()))) {
            $this->_fault('invalid_data');
        }
        $tag->setStatus($data['status']);
    }

    try {
        $tag->save();
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $this->_fault('save_error', $e->getMessage());
    }

    return true;
}
```

In my controller I have this :

```
public function clickAction()
{
    $tagString = $this->getRequest()->getParam('tag');
    $tagByName = Mage::getModel('tag/tag')->loadByName($tagString);
    $tagId  = $tagByName->getTagId();
    $basePopularity = ['base_popularity' => '13']; // hard coding while testing
    Mage::getModel('tag/api')->update($tagId, $basePopularity, 1);
}
```

If I put a log statement in this part of the update function :

```
    try {
        // log stuff
        $tag->save();
    }
```

I can see it makes it to that `try` but there is no change in the data.  What did I screw up?  Any other ideas on how I can update the popularity of a tag through a controller?  Using this same method and adding `'name' => 'blah'` to that `$data` array parameter works fine..

I also found in `Mage_Tag_Model_Indexer_Summary.php` this method defined in the PHPdoc `* @method Mage_Tag_Model_Indexer_Summary setPopularity(int $value)` Maybe that is what I need... can someone provide an example showing how I could use that magic setter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);` at the start of your `clickAction` function. `base_popularity` can only be updated from admin store.